# ¿Cómo brindar permisos dependiendo del usuario?

Tags: php, html5

Estoy practicando PHP y me surgió la duda.

Es decir, un usuario normal puede solo publicar, un moderador puede publicar y editar, y un administrador tiene todos los permisos en el sitio web. ¿Cómo hago eso?

¿Tendría que crear una base de datos con ciertas 'características especiales'? ¿O es puro código en si?

Comment: Te sugiero revisar el control de acceso basado en roles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control, y aqui un ejemplo de implementacion https://www.sitepoint.com/role-based-access-control-in-php/

Comment: Hoose, creo que esta pregunta es *muy* ámplia. Lo que comentas es el comportamiento interno de la mayoría de aplicaciones web internas y se puede hacer de muchas maneras. Quizá lo mejor es que intentes alguna y luego si tienes dudas vuelvas a preguntar.

Comment: @MiquelColl La pregunta la hice por que la verdad no se ni como empezar.

Comment: @Hoose comienza buscando información sobre _permisos ACL (Access Control List)_ encontrarás bastante información y ejemplos de uso. Entiende su funcionamiento. Prueba a implementar alguno de los que veas y que te sientas cómodo con el código. Y los problemas que surjan puedes ir preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Lo lógico, sería plantear una base de datos, donde se registrasen los usuarios, las contraseñas (que te sugiero que sean cifradas), y los privilegios.

A la hora de validar el usuario, sería cuestión de leer los permisos que tiene asignado el usuario y al principio de cada página, fijar los permisos que se necesitan para entrar, o bien mostrar los controles según los perfiles de cada usuario

Comment: Tu solución es una de muchas, debería quedar claro en tu respuesta. Por ejemplo, podrías utilizar  un LDAP o el sistema de usuarios y grupos de Unix/Linux. En mi opinión, siempre que sea posible y/o lo amerite, no deberías usar una solución ad-hoc (propia) para temas relacionados con seguridad.